# Interpolation Search, searching on a descending array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting, interpolation

I want to modify this algorithm so that it can find values within an array which has been sorted in descending order. This currently only works for ascending.

```
public static int interpo(double[] array, double key, int order)
{
    int low = 0, high = array.Length - 1;
    int pos = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while ((low <= high) && (key >= array[low]) && (key <= array[high]))
    {
        count++;
        pos = Convert.ToInt32(low + (high - low) / (array[high] - array[low]) * 
            (key - array[low]));

        if (array[pos] == key)
        {
            // Write out the position and the value of whats in the position
            Console.WriteLine("\n     {0} : {1}", pos, array[pos]);                   
            break;
        }

        if (array[pos] < key)
            low = pos + 1;
        else
            high = pos - 1;

        // If the count is greater than the array size, do the following
        if (count > array.Length) 
        {
            // Pass through the position within the array to the close element 
            // method, which will display the closest values within the array
            closeelement(array, key, pos);

            // Return nothing                      
            return -2;  
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to be able to pass the order in which the array has been sorted in the parameter `order`, you just need to change your termination condition, like so (using 0=descending, 1=ascending):

```
public static int interpo(double[] array, double key, int order)
{
    int low = 0, high = array.Length - 1;
    int pos = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while ((low <= high) && ((order == 1 && (key >= array[low]) && (key <= array[high])) || (order == 0 && (key <= array[low]) && (key >= array[high]))))
    {
        count++;
        pos = Convert.ToInt32(low + (high - low) / (array[high] - array[low]) *
            (key - array[low]));

        if (array[pos] == key)
        {
            // Write out the position and the value of whats in the position
            Console.WriteLine("\n     {0} : {1}", pos, array[pos]);
            break;
        }

        if (array[pos] < key)
            low = pos + 1;
        else
            high = pos - 1;

        // If the count is greater than the array size, do the following
        if (count > array.Length)
        {
            // Pass through the position within the array to the close element 
            // method, which will display the closest values within the array
            closeelement(array, key, pos);

            // Return nothing                      
            return -2;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need the function to **only** be able to find values in a descending array, just change your termination condition like so:

```
public static int interpo(double[] array, double key, int order)
{
    int low = 0, high = array.Length - 1;
    int pos = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while ((low <= high) && ((key <= array[low]) && (key >= array[high])))
    {
        count++;
        pos = Convert.ToInt32(low + (high - low) / (array[high] - array[low]) * 
            (key - array[low]));

        if (array[pos] == key)
        {
            // Write out the position and the value of whats in the position
            Console.WriteLine("\n     {0} : {1}", pos, array[pos]);                   
            break;
        }

        if (array[pos] < key)
            low = pos + 1;
        else
            high = pos - 1;

        // If the count is greater than the array size, do the following
        if (count > array.Length) 
        {
            // Pass through the position within the array to the close element 
            // method, which will display the closest values within the array
            closeelement(array, key, pos);

            // Return nothing                      
            return -2;  
        }
    }

    return - 1;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps, sorry.

Comment: Did you bother to try the provided code? How does the result compare to your expected result?

Comment: I don't need an order parameter, i just need to modify the code to it will work on a descending array. I'll add the order stuff afterwards. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok. Edited my answer... [Here's](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrui48) a fiddle I made for you to test it.

Comment: I see where you're going with that, i tried it and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying this algorithm works for in ascending order sorted arrays, I can think of the following approaches:

1. Switch the index accesses, i.e. instead of accessing the element at index `i`, access the element at `array.Length - i - 1`

   Example:

   Instead of writing `array[low]` write `array[array.Length - 1 - low]`. You can 
   simplify this by introducing a variable at the beginning of the method:

   ```
   int l = array.Length - 1;
   ```

   Then in your code do for example:

   ```
   while ((low <= high) && (key >= array[l - low]) && (key <= array[l - high])) 
   { /* ... */ }
   ```
2. Reverse the array before you execute the algorithm. You can do this using `Array.Reverse()`.

Comment: I don't want to reverse the array, sorry. And i'm unsure what you mean by the index accesses.

Comment: i have, Index was outside the bounds of the array. Sorry if i'm missing something, i'm not an expert at c#