# How to write interpolation search recursively? - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion, search, interpolation

I need to write a recursive function that finds an element in an array using interpolation method. Preferably it should be based on recursion.

Here is my code:

```
static int? InterpolationSearch(int[] arr, int value, int left, int right)
{
    if (arr[left] == value) return left;
    else if (left == right || arr[left] == arr[right]) return null;

    int index = left + (value - arr[left]) * (right - left) / (arr[right] - arr[left]);

    if (arr[index] == value) return index;
    else if (arr[left] < value) return InterpolationSearch(arr, value, index + 1, right);
    else return InterpolationSearch(arr, value, left, index - 1);
}
```

When searching in big arrays (about 1000 elements and more), it throws StackOverflowException.

What is the problem?

Comment: your recursion is called too many times; in other words, you never exit from this methods. what's the simplest input this methods throws for?

Comment: Print out left and right in method so you can debug code.  Most likely left  or right is outside the size of the array.

Comment: There are many examples of how to do this out there, here are some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048866/interpolation-search-searching-on-a-descending-array https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/interpolation-search https://www.codeproject.com/articles/177363/searching-and-sorting-algorithms-via-c

Comment: @Isma, it all non-recursive functions

Comment: Debug with this call `InterpolationSearch(new int [] {10, 20, 30, 40}, 12 , 0, 3);`. It will exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: I found solution. Thanks to @jdweng for advice.

Comment: I had already converted one of the methods above to be recursive, so I added it as an answer too, you will reduce the cyclomatic complexity a bit with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you never exit the function, here is another example of how to achieve this, which is working for me:

```
public static int InterpolationSearch(int[] array, int value)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = array.Length - 1;
    return InterpolationSearch(array, value, ref low, ref high);
}

private static int InterpolationSearch(int[] array, int value, ref int low, ref int high)
{
    int index = -1;

    if (low <= high)
    {
        index = (int)(low + (((int)(high - low) / (array[high] - array[low])) * (value - array[low])));
        if (array[index] == value) 
        {
            return index;
        }
        else
        {
            if (array[index] < value)
                low = index + 1;
            else
                high = index - 1;
        } 

        return InterpolationSearch(array, value, ref low, ref high);
    }

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was just my inattention.

Just had to swap `InterpolationSearch(arr, value, index + 1, right)` and `InterpolationSearch(arr, value, left, index - 1)` functions.